# Escape from if statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two files:

```
file1 = "line1\n line2\n line3\n"
file2 =  "line1\n line2\n line3\n line4\n line5\n"
```

and what I want is:

to print all the lines in file2 replacing only the lines with common length with file 1.

I tried this.

```
for line in file1.splitlines():
    for l in file2.splitlines():
        if len(line) == len(l):
            print file2.replace(l, line)
```

The problem is that the result contains only the lines with common length, and not all the lines in file2. I understand that this is due to the if statement, but how can I escape from this.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question?

Comment: With nested loops, you print up to (file1 * file2) lines because you iterate second file for each line in first file. You need only one loop, definitely not nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? I don't really understand your question, sorry:

```
for line in file1.splitlines():
    for i,l in enumerate(file2.splitlines()):
        if len(line) == len(l):
            file2[i] = file2.replace(l, line)
print file2
```

Comment: It prints file2 without changes

Comment: @5555555555, Answer updated. Should work now, hopefully. If not, please put more code in question and I will try to debug it further. Good Luck. :)

Comment: file2[i] = file2.replace(l, line)
TypeError: 'unicode' object does not support item assignment

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may not be exactly as you specified. You could do something like this instead:

```
def file_compare(file1, file2): 
    for file1line, file2line in zip(file1.splitlines(), file2.splitlines()):
        yield file1line if len(file1line) == len(file2line) else file2line

file3.writelines(file_compare(file1, file2))
```

That walks through the files together, per line. For every line, it returns one or the other depending on the constraints (in this case, if the lengths are equal, return the line from file1, else return the line from file 2). The writelines can take this generator as input to write the lines to another file.

Comment: but the number of lines in the two files is not equel

Answer (score 0):

Assumming file1 is shorter:

```
lines1 = file1.splitlines()
lines2 = file2.splitlines()
for num, line in enumerate(lines1):
  line2 = lines2[num]
  print line if len(line2) == len(line) else line2
for line in lines2[num+1:]:
  print line
```

With actual files it's easier because you can abuse next() to iterate lines:

```
file1 = open("file1.txt")
file2 = open("file2.txt")
for line in file1:
  line2 = next(file2)
  print line if len(line2) == len(line) else line2
for line in file2:
  print line
```

Well, you can use itertools.zip_longest but it's cheating:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
file1 = "line1\n line2\n line3\n"
file2 =  "line1\n line2\n line3\n line4\n line5\n"
for line1, line2 in izip_longest(file1.splitlines(), file2.splitlines(), fillvalue=''):
  print line1 if len(line2) == len(line1) else line2
```

Edit: in py2 zip_longest is called izip_longest.